# Repeating a several numbers a set number of times in VBA

Tags: vba, repeat

I have a column of 47 numbers in a column in spreadsheet. In another sheet I want the numbers to be transposed into a row. I did so using this code

```
Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Calc"

Dim k As Integer

For k = 1 To 47

Worksheets("Calc").Cells(1, k).Value = Worksheets("Reformulering").Cells(k + 1, 2).Value

Next k
```

However, I want each number to be repeated 12 times in the row before the next number comes. Can anyone think of a method to do this?

Best,

ID

Comment: Paste your Input and your desired output.

Comment: add another loop, and add this to k, so `for z=1 to 12`, then `.cells(1,k+z).value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add another loop that runs from 1 untill 12 like this:

```
Worksheets.Add(Before:=Worksheets(1)).Name = "Calc"

Dim k As Integer
Dim i As Integer

For k = 1 To 47
    For i = 1 To 12
        Worksheets("Calc").Cells(1, ((k - 1) * 12) + i).Value = Worksheets("Reformulering").Cells(k + 1, 2).Value
    Next i
Next k
```

Comment: Don't worry --- fixed it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @pkpkPPkafa it's running on my file , are you sure you copied the contents without errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Transpose the values without loop

```
[Calc!A1:L47] = Application.Transpose([Reformulering!B2:AV2])
```

Similar to copying the range, selecting `Calc!A1:L1`, `Paste Special...`, check Transpose, and OK

Comment: That doesnt repeat the number though, does it?